# TFS Build 2018 with TFS 2015 Server, is it possible?

Tags: tfs, build, tfs-2015

We cannot update TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 because we have SQL 2012 and TFS 2018 need a higher version. It will take another 6-8 months before we upgrade SQL 2012 to SQL 2016 or latest.

My question is, Can I do TFS Build 2018 with TFS 2015 Server, is it possible? I am not sure about it.

Thanks.

Comment: For TFS build which one are you talking about, the old XAML build or the new vNext?

Comment: new build server vNext, Not XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "Yes, but it would be a huge pain and be an awful, hacky process". I started to write some of it out, and then I realized that there's no point in doing it.

You need an installation of TFS 2018 to use any of its features.

That requires SQL 2016.

That means you'd have to stand up an entire new instance of TFS.

At that point, you might as well just stand up new hardware/VMs and do a migration upgrade.

To summarize:

- **Q:** Can I use TFS 2018 build with TFS 2015?

  - **A:** Not without installing a new instance of TFS 2018.
- **Q:** Can I use TFS 2018 without SQL Server 2016?

  - **A:** No.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I was thinking same, I may create the new environment for Dev and prep for TFS 2018 and verify new features and meanwhile, SQL will be upgraded to 2016 or higher.